Integer overflow warning only when using const keyword
I'm encountering a warning with the const keyword in C++ when using clang++ v. 17.0.1 or newer, with the flag -Winteger-overflow.
Here's the code snippet:
int foo_const()
{
    const auto min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); // const keyword
    return - min; // warning: overflow in expression; result is -2147483648 with type 'int' [-Winteger-overflow]
}

int foo()
{
    auto min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();   // no const keyword
    return - min; // no warning
}

In the foo_const function, I'm getting a warning about potential integer overflow. However, the same operation in the non-const foo function compiles without a warning.
I'd appreciate some help understanding why the const keyword triggers the overflow warning in this specific case.

I think the overflow is happening in the next line return - min;

Without the const keyword, it seems like it allows for the possibility that min could be reassigned to a higher value that doesn't overflow when negated.

right. I've put the comment on the previous line because the const keyword is triggering this behaviour. I'm gonna change the comments, thanks.

"I'd appreciate some help understanding why the const keyword triggers the overflow warning in this specific case." -- I think it would be more interesting to understand why the overflow warning is not triggered in the other case. Since the overflow provably happens in both.

what john says: https://godbolt.org/z/YvaMPfhz1. You should include the warning message in the question.

Interestingly gcc has the same behaviour, warning only in the const case.

The C++ standard does not require that a compiler detects this UB.  In that the compiler does this kind of "lint" checking and warn about the UB is a bonus, even though it only does so in the foo_const scenario.  UB sanitizer catches the UB in both routines.

const int might generally be promoted into constexpr int, allowing further check.

When you use the const qualifier, the compiler will automatically replace uses of the variable with the initial value. When it tries to do this in the expression -min, the result is a value that's outside the range of int.
In the version without const, the reference to min in the return statement is treated normally, rather than having the initial value substituted. So there's no known overflow.
The compiler conceivably could detect that the variable is not reassigned between initialization and use in the return statement. But it apparently doesn't do that for the purpose of detecting errors like this (it might do it later in the optimizer).

depending which compiler. clang happily may nag in either case, but without additional flags for static analisis it does question return statement, not assignment statement. A logic probably based on fact that this can be template code and therefore unused. Anyway, warning is result of inlining possibility, as you wrote.

Short answer: the compiler is just not smart enough. Both functions result in the same UB.
